# How to use grafana cloud and its prometheus with istio and kiali?

Tags: istio, istio-kiali, istio-prometheus

How to use grafana cloud and its prometheus with istio and kiali?

istio comes with its prometheus and kiali is too configured to read from istio installed prometheus. However, I have grafana cloud stack setup and want to use it with istio and kiali.